# Does it make sense to set session=null after session.close()?

Tags: java, session, connection, httpsession

consider this bit of code:

```
public void foo(){
       try{
        //some cool statements here
      }
      finally {
         if(session != null){
             session.close();
             sesssion = null;
          }
     }
   }
```

Since the session is closed, is the value assigned to session going to make sense? Please provide some valuable insights.

Comment: It's generally useless. It could be done to tell the GC that `session` is ready to be collected, but you have no control over the GC. Also, if your method ends after the `finally` block session will be `null` anyway.

Comment: Is there any case like "session deletion race condition" in Java where setting it to null may be helpful? https://developer.joomla.org/news/738-more-details-about-the-session-deletion-race-condition.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting local variable to `null` is unnecessary, to wit, it's part of CERT Oracle Secure Coding Standard's [Recommendations](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/OBJ54-J.+Do+not+attempt+to+help+the+garbage+collector+by+setting+local+reference+variables+to+null)

> Setting local reference variables to null to "help the garbage collector" is unnecessary. It adds clutter to the code and can make maintenance difficult. Java just-in-time compilers (JITs) can perform an equivalent liveness analysis, and most implementations do so.

Answer (score 0):

Setting variables to null can be useful in scenarios where the objects themselves have become useless, in this example a closed session. Such objects usually document that after calling `close` or a similar method, all further operations on that object will fail, e.g. by throwing `IllegalStateException`. In those cases it arguably makes sense to erase such an instance, especially if other parts of the code expect and check for a null instance as a sign of "no connection".

As stated in other answers, garbace collection however is not a valid reason to set a variable to null.

Comment: yes, for such cases to check null instance that makes a little sense but technically does it make any other concrete sense?